# Is it possible to add a user to an Analytics profile using the Management API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Instead of asking clients to log in their Analytics Admin panel, click "New User" and then entering my email address, I would like just to point them to a link where they can authorize an app which will do that automatically for them.
Here's a printscreen of the process: https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Nyn.png

Can this be done with one of the Analytics APIs? Or is there already an app which can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Google Analytics management API is currently read only.

And it doesn't have any methods that handle users. Not even user listing.